# How to get list of linkedin learning courses with REST Api

Tags: linkedin-api

I looks for a guide or docs about how to get linkedin learning courses list with Rest Api and to present them to users in my website according to their skills

i did'nt find a way to fetch them , i dont need to use the courses in my website, I just want to show their details to the user

Comment: Have you took a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/learning/integrations/retrieve-an-individual-learning-object ?

Comment: yes , is the only way to use it with admin account ?